# Remove Metro results from Settings search

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-search

Is there a way to remove Metro settings (a.k.a. PC Settings) results from Settings search in Charms?
Or at least, is there a way to move these results to the bottom?

I know I'm not *completely* crazy is because I have another computer which does not show these results (I have no idea how I did that, it might have been an accident).

The other strange thing is that Windows purposefully places the metro results at the top, since the most obvious match would be the Control Panel item "Mouse" - lexically, it matches my search term exactly.

[image]